# Multiple markers in google maps, multiple maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to built 2 google maps in a same page. One of those maps has several markers...

```
function initializeMap() {



    var locations = [
        ['PARIS - FRANCE', 485.810,2.2629],
        ['PARIS - FRANCE', 49.046,2.330],
        ['PARIS - FRANCE', 48.4331,2.2134],
        ['PALERMO - ITALY', 38.1033,1.3527],
        ['ROME - ITALY', 41.4846,1.21511]
    ];





var lat = '48.900401'; 
var lon = '2.231761'; 


var contentString = '<p style="color:#8fd522; font-weight: bold;">XXX</p>';



var centerLon = lon - 0.0105;

var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, centerLon),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

//Bind map to elemet with id map-canvas
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    title: 'XXX'
});

var infowindowW = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindowW.open(map, marker);
});

infowindowW.open(map, marker);

var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: true,
    draggable: true,
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(66.6846, -67.21511),
    zoom: 2.82,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};


var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-net'), myOptions);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
         map: map2,
         title: locations[i][0]
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: locations[i][0]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
         return function() {
             infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
             infowindow.open(map2, marker);
         }
    })(marker, i));
}
}
```

The markers of map2 are not clickable...I tried to do `marker[i]` in the loop but it just make the code invalid (`window.initializeMap` is not a *function*)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Zoom is an integer. For some reason, this:

```
   zoom: 2.82,
```

causes the problem.  Change that to `2` and [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8Lge5kyr/4/).

code snippet:

```js
function initializeMap() {
  var locations = [
    ['PARIS - FRANCE', 48.810, 2.2629],
    ['PARIS - FRANCE', 49.046, 2.330],
    ['PARIS - FRANCE', 48.4331, 2.2134],
    ['PALERMO - ITALY', 38.1033, 1.3527],
    ['ROME - ITALY', 41.4846, 1.21511]
  ];

  var lat = '48.900401';
  var lon = '2.231761';
  var contentString = '<p style="color:#8fd522; font-weight: bold;">XXX</p>';
  var centerLon = lon - 0.0105;
  var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, centerLon),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  //Bind map to elemet with id map-canvas
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    title: 'XXX'
  });

  var infowindowW = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindowW.open(map, marker);
  });

  infowindowW.open(map, marker);

  var myOptions2 = {
    scrollwheel: true,
    draggable: true,
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(66.6846, -67.21511),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };


  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-net'), myOptions2);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map2,
      title: locations[i][0]
    });

    var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: locations[i][0]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', (function(marker2, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow2.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow2.open(map2, marker2);
      };
    })(marker2, i));
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas,
#map-canvas-net {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="map-canvas-net" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```