# Google Maps API - Multiple Markers with Multiple Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a new page that basically has 2 maps on there with their own markers.

I've managed to get the first map working using the code supplied here http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/ which has worked perfectly... but when I've tried copying the code and changing the map canvas the 2nd map doesn't load.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script2.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize2";
    document.body.appendChild(script2);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
        ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
    ];

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
        '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
        '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}

function initialize2() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
        ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
    ];

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
        '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
        '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}
</script>
```

Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: related question: [Multiple markers in google maps, multiple maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282877/multiple-markers-in-google-maps-multiple-maps)

Comment: I get a javascript error/warning in the console: `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`  That said, I do get two maps, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  Do you actually have both a div with id="map_canvas" and one with id="map_canvas2", and do both of them have a size?

Comment: [fiddle with both maps](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qnutxgn8/)

Comment: Thanks for asking, this helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're loading the Maps API JS files twice, with the

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
document.body.appendChild(script);

// Asynchronously Load the map API 
var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize2";
document.body.appendChild(script2);
```

You don't need to do that, just load it once.

Then your two functions `initialize` and `initialize2` are almost identical, apart from the name of your map canvas.  That defeats the point of using a function.  Get rid of initialize2.

Move what you've currently got in initialize into its own function; let's call it `createMap`.  Create a new initialize function, called via the map callback parameter, that calls this createMap function twice, with whatever parameters you need to setup the differences between them.

Something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    createMap('map_canvas');
    createMap('map_canvas2');
}

function createMap(mapCanvas) {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapCanvas), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
        ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
    ];

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
        '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
        '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
        '</div>']
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = map.addListener(('bounds_changed', function() {
        this.setZoom(14);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
}
```

You'd maybe want to setup the markers in the initialize function, and pass it as an additional parameter to the createMap function, assuming each map has different markers.